# Is it bad to Instantiate the fileinfo class within a foreach loop? Is there a better way with C#?

Tags: c#, class, loops, foreach

My code below works but I'm concerned that its bad practice or may cause memory issues. But with my limited knowledge its the best way I've found. Can it be done any better?

Thanks

```
static void Main()
{
    // Directory of files.
    const string dir = @"C:\Test";

    // File names.
    string[] fns = Directory.GetFiles(dir);

    // Order by size.
    var sort = from fn in fns
               orderby new FileInfo(fn).Length descending
               select fn;

    // List files.
    foreach (string n in sort)
    {
        Console.Write(n);
        Console.Write(" ");
        FileInfo f = new FileInfo(n);
        long file = f.Length;
        Console.WriteLine(file);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I doubt there's a problem with this, but you could use `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()` instead if you want.

Comment: This would be a better fit at http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: If you are looping sort to get only file length why not store file length using your linq query and sort that and display length from sort collection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instantiating the `FileInfo` instances isn't a problem. It's a managed object that doesn't implement `IDisposable` which means the garbage collector should be able to clean everything up nicely.

The issue I see is that you're creating two instances per file (one in your LINQ query, the other in your loop). Why not just modify your query so that you only need the instantiation a single time:

```
var sortedFiles = fns.Select(fn => new FileInfo(fn))
                     .OrderBy(f => f.Length);

foreach(var file in sortedFiles)
{
    Console.Write(file.Name);
    Console.Write(" ");
    Console.WriteLine(file.Length);
}
```

Comment: Hey that works great. Can that LINQ expression be written without lambdas? They confuse the heck out of me.

Answer (score 6):

I see no problem with the `FileInfo` instantiation you have.  It looks like a managed object.  let the garbage collector worry about it.

Now the `FileStream` object that you may or may not be using `FileInfo` with should be `close`d.  a `using` statement will do the heavy lifting for you on that front

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a problem with your code but I would use `DirectoryInfo("path")`. it has a method `GetFiles()` which return `FileInfo` array. So you don't need to create it twice..

```
var sort = new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles().OrderBy(f => f.Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a `DirectoryInfo` from your directory path.
2. Use it's `GetFiles` or `EnumerateFiles` method to get `FileInfo` objects directly.

Is this what you were looking for?

```
static void Main()
{
    // Directory of files.
    const string dir = @"C:\Test";

    // File names.
    var files = new DirectoryInfo(dir).EnumerateFiles();

    // Order by size.
    var sort = from file in files
               orderby file.Length descending
               select file;

    // List files.
    foreach (var file in sort)
    {
        Console.Write(file.FullName);
        Console.Write(" ");
        Console.WriteLine(file.Length);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```